# Starting main application process from service

Tags: android

I have a background service that receives notification even after my main app's process is killed.

I am trying to get my service to start my main application on certain notifications that it receives. I have this, but it is not working, my main activity does not start.

```
 Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
 dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 getApplication().startActivity(dialogIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try referring to the Service context itself, I'm not sure if you're getting the context you're expecting:

```
Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(MyService.this, MainActivity.class);
 dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 MyService.this.startActivity(dialogIntent);
```